# How do I make each column in an array fit the random numbers of a bingo card?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to code a Bingo game in C right now

How do I make it so the first column in an array generates only a number from 1 to 15, the second column only generates between 16 to 30, etc?

I am making code in C language right now that reads as follows.

```
      for(int column = 0; column < 5; column++){
      board[row][column] = rand() %75;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min + rand() % (max - min + 1)` to get a number between `min` and `max`.

Comment: So I would put that after the second row or would i replace the second row?

Comment: Since each column also can't contain duplicates, better to fill an array with the 15 numbers of the column, shuffle, and take the top 5.

Comment: I was not aware of the fact that each column should not have duplicates. If so your method is better suited indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Random numbers will contain duplicates, so the right thing to do here is to fill each column by first creating an array of its 15 possible numbers: i.e., 1..15 for B, 15..30 for I, etc. Then perform a partial Fisher-Yates shuffle (you don't need to shuffle all 15, just 5), and use those first 5 numbers for the column.